# Can I run the Eclipse c++ Formatters from the command line

Tags: eclipse, plugins, code-formatting

I found [this page](http://blogs.operationaldynamics.com/andrew/software/java-gnome/eclipse-code-format-from-command-line.html) which shows how to run the Java formatter but I cannot find similar resources to run the built-in C/C++ formatters.

It is possible To do this?

Answer (score 0):

Its possible. You can call Eclipse with he parameter:
eclipse.exe -application org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCodeFormatter -config "./org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs" "../lala/tmp"  ...

Answer (score 0):

From the eclipse [doc](https://help.eclipse.org/2021-09/index.jsp)
C/C++ Development User Guide > Tasks > Using the Formatter Application:

```
eclipse -application org.eclipse.cdt.core.CodeFormatter [ OPTIONS ] [ -config <configFile> ] <files>
```